# produce a clear giant heatmap in python

Tags: python, heatmap

I got a gigantic 26x387 numpy array of one's and zero's that I want to show in a heatmap. The problem is when I generate this plot, the heatmap is way to small and I can't zoom in enough to get any clear information.. Is there a way to fix this?

This is my current code:

```
geneResults, cellNames, fileName = getheatmapArray(Data) #here I generate the array

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.imshow(geneResults, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("gist_yarg"), interpolation="nearest")
fig.tight_layout()

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(interestingGenes)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(cellNames)))

ax.set_xticklabels(interestingGenes, fontsize = 5)
ax.set_yticklabels(cellNames, fontsize = 5)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
        rotation_mode="anchor")

plt.colorbar(heatmap)

plt.savefig("{}_heatmap.pdf".format(fileName))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. simply using fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = 20,20) instead of fig, ax = plt.subplots() fixes the problem

Answer (score 2):

Well you should set size of the figure in inches, example:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

You might try out multiple sizes and see what best fits you.

Comment: But when I try this, It wont show the figure any more... I tried really large or low numbers but all I get is a white figure

Comment: probably as it is very large, it takes long for pdf reader to render it, save it as well as png to see if anything changes

Comment: I tried waiting or saving it to png and still a white screen...

Comment: @MarkWekking can you provide the data i.e. on git or so?

Comment: when using fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10)) instead of plt.figure(figsize(20,10)) fixes the problem! when I use plt.figure it generates a new figure that is empty